# adding links to data table rows in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm using django. Here is my code:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-bordered text-nowrap w-100">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="wd-15p">devEUI</th>
                    <th class="wd-15p">appID</th>
                    <th class="wd-20p">Type machine</th>
                    <th class="wd-20p">Date création</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for machine in machines %}
                    <tr>
                        <a href="{% url 'details_of_element' %}">
                            <td>{{machine.devEUI}}</td>
                            <td>{{machine.appID}}</td>
                            <td>{{machine.type_machine}}</td>
                            <td>{{machine.date_creation}}</td>
                        </a>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

It does not work. I want to add a link to each line to see the details of each item. How can I do this with django, jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following code

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-bordered text-nowrap w-100">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="wd-15p">devEUI</th>
                    <th class="wd-15p">appID</th>
                    <th class="wd-20p">Type machine</th>
                    <th class="wd-20p">Date création</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for machine in machines %}
                    <tr data-href="{% url 'details_url' %}">
                       
                        <td>{{machine.devEUI}}</td>
                        <td>{{machine.appID}}</td>
                        <td>{{machine.type_machine}}</td>
                        <td>{{machine.date_creation}}</td>
                       
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() =>{
            const rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr[data-href]");
            rows.forEach(row => {
                row.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    window.location.href = row.dataset.href;
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For detail_view one would need some identification to get a particular instance of the model in **Django**. Usually it is unique primary key such as **id**. To specify this identification we need to define it in `urls.py` of your app.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

# importing views from views..py
from .views import detail_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('<id>', detail_view, name='details_of_element' ),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# relative import of Model
from .models import Machine

# pass id attribute from urls
def detail_view(request, id):
    machine = Machine.objects.get(id = id)
    return render(request, "detail_view.html", {'machine': machine})
```

**machine_list.html**

```
<tbody>
    {% for machine in machines %}
        <tr>
            <a href="{% url 'details_of_element' machine.id %}">
                <td>{{machine.devEUI}}</td>
                <td>{{machine.appID}}</td>
                <td>{{machine.type_machine}}</td>
                <td>{{machine.date_creation}}</td>
            </a>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem lies with the hypertext link (href). It does not work.

Comment: past your urls.py and html file

Comment: Can confirm that tables like this do work. I have several. Each link needs to contain identification of the entity summarized in the table row, as per this answer.